# Split a lengthy Excel worksheet into multiple yearly tabs keeping cell references

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lengthy worksheet divided into yearly data blocks, each line containing (among other fields) a person name and at least one column pointing to the same person data for a different year like for instance:

- at line 1731 (user A year 2016), column T calculates and accumulates data from the same user A obtained one year earlier (2015) with the following formula: =((T1553/E1553)*J1553)

I would like to break this lengthy file into multiple worksheets each worksheet representing one year block.
Creating the worksheets is not the issue. The issue lies in keeping the references across worksheets so that the calculations can still be done.

Is there a way to achieve this or am I stuck with this lengthy linear model?

Comment: Create the worksheets and ***cut*** & paste from the master worksheet to each individual worksheet.

Comment: Right....This, I know...The thing is I'd like to do it with VBA since it's going to be part of a larger process.
Using wsSource.Range(cell1,cell2).Copy and wsDest.Range(cell1,cell2).Paste will not paste the correct references to the previous year block.
Also tried PasteSpecial with xlPasteFormulas, xlPasteFormats and all but none seems to be able to work. Just like if the reference was completely lost.